# Show buddypress profile fields in a multsite blog

Tags: multisite, buddypress

I want to show my users profile fields in theirs child blogs of my site.

On the main template i use

```
<? echo bp_get_profile_field_data( 'field=Name'); ?>
```

On the child theme that i use for my users blogs this dont work.

Checking $bp var i can see that $bp->displayed_user its empty

There is way to do tihs?

I just want to show on the multisite blogs created by users their profile of buddypress.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

try switch to the main blog where buddypress is installed, echo the profile fields then switch back to the current blog.

```
$bp_blog = 1; // the blog id of your buddypress install, often 1
switch_to_blog($bp_blog);
echo bp_get_profile_field_data( 'field=Name');
restore_current_blog();
```

if that doesn't work, maybe the user in question is not a member of your main blog. You might need to add all users in the network to the buddypress blog if they are not already.